# add suffix without using "additional-suffix" in split

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu, split

-> any other way to add suffix without using "--additional-suffix" , because i want to run this even with an old version that does not have the option "--additional-suffix"

```
//split list of all files generated so that reading will not be a problem
sprintf(command,
        "split -l 50000 --additional-suffix=.txt -d -a 3 %s %s_all_files_",
        all_files_fname, time_buf);
system(command);
```

=================================================================================

split: unrecognized option '--additional-suffix=.txt'
Try `split --help' for more information.
cat: .20141104_134258_check_dupl_song_num_result.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: So, did you try doing as it asked? Man-pages in the intertubes: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html

Comment: sadly my version does not have the option " --additional-suffix=SUFFIX" when i look at it in my terminal. I tried to add another line of command "for i in %s %s_all_files_*; do mv $i $i.txt; done" to add the suffix but it cause complication later on, so i was hoping to have a better solution.

Comment: So, look what the command answers.

Comment: If your question is really "how do I do this from C", reading the [`split` source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/split.c;h=ec0da7debdb315d1806a91e74c70844068b70d5f;hb=HEAD) ought to be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small GNU Awk script which does what you are asking for.

```
awk -v prefix="all_files_" suffix=".txt" 'NR%5000==1 { if (NR>1) close(file);
        file=sprintf("%s%03i%s", prefix, ++i, suffix }
    { print > file }' inputfile
```